# how to import windows skype history if mint linux skype?

Tags: history, skype, linux-mint

I used `skype` in my pc have a `windows 7`. Now, i backup skype history and format pc then install `Mint linux os.`

Now. i am install skype but how i can `import old skype history in new skype mint linux os?`

Where are store `logs of skype history` in mint linux?
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Skype folder is:

/home/*user*/.Skype/

Maybe it will work.